# How to sign pdf with tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, ssl

I wanna to make an eletronic sign on my pdf file in the server , so I have make a file .crt using TBS X509 for that . I'am using TCPDF to the PDF so I 've use it this code to set signature to my file : 
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps
But it doesn't work , I dont know with's the problem :(

```
<?php

require_once('config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf.php');
 $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);



// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 052');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH,   PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 052', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

 //set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

 //set some language-dependent strings
 $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);


 // set certificate file


 $certificate = 'file://user.crt';


 // set additional information
  $info = array(
'Name' => 'TCPDF',
'Location' => 'Office',
'Reason' => 'Testing TCPDF',
'ContactInfo' => 'http://www.tcpdf.org',
);

  // set document signature
 $pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, $info);

 // set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);

 // add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

 // print a line of text
  $text = 'This is a <b color="#FF0000">digitally signed document</b> using the default (example) <b>tcpdf.crt</b> certificate.<br />To validate this signature you have to load the <b color="#006600">tcpdf.fdf</b> on the Arobat Reader to add the certificate to <i>List of Trusted Identities</i>.<br /><br />For more information check the source code of this example and the source code documentation for the <i>setSignature()</i> method.<br /><br /><a href="http://www.tcpdf.org">www.tcpdf.org</a>';
```

$pdf->writeHTML($text, true, 0, true, 0);

```
 // create content for signature (image and/or text)
 $pdf->Image('signatureImage.jpg', 180, 60, 15, 15, 'PNG');

   // define active area for signature appearance
 $pdf->setSignatureAppearance(180, 60, 15, 15);


   $pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(180, 80, 15, 15);



 //Close and output PDF document
 $pdf->Output('example_052.pdf', 'I');















?>
```

how to test it to an existing pdf file ?

Comment: `$certificate = 'file:///user.crt';` looks wrong. Unless the file really is in `/user.crt`?

Comment: yes sorry ; but I've tried  /user.crt , I 've alwayes the problem , nothing is displayed

Comment: this code doesn't work for that instruction : $pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, $info);
any idea !!!